# Xamarin loginpage and C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hi there is some way to enter a default username and password in the C sharp code which means that when entering the username and password entered in the code, it goes to the next page and writes incorrectly so it says that there is an incorrect username and password. The idea is just having a default username and password I choose myself. The code I use is in Xaml's:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <Label Text=""
           TextColor="#000000"
           FontSize="10"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="Center" />

    <Entry x:Name="Username" Keyboard="Default" Placeholder="Brukernavn" ></Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="Password" Keyboard="Default" IsPassword="True" Placeholder="Passord"></Entry>
    <Button x:Name="Btn_signin" Text="Login" FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="#000000"
    BackgroundColor="#50C6E0"
    BorderWidth = "0"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Unclear. Do you want a developer default, so you don't need to enter your credentials over and over again whilst you are developing, or do you want to prevent profiles to be created or logged on with certain user names (blacklist), which authentication method are you using in the backend?

Comment: Do not use anything for now. Must only have a default username and password in the app so people must log in to view the content. so nobody gets access to the app when I publish it

Comment: then it is not a default, but the opposite: a hardcoded master password. just compare the posted values with two constants in the server-side code. be aware that the password is not encrypted for transmission unless you use SSL or another secure encryption method.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Text` Property in `OnAppearing()` method of the page.

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        UsernameEntry.Text = "Your Default UserName";
        PasswordEntry.Text="Your Default PassWord"
    }
```

Then on `ButtonClick` event you can check User Name and Password and display error message accordingly.

Add Xaml Code for Click Event:

```
 <Button x:Name="Btn_signin" Text="Login" FontAttributes="Bold"
        TextColor="#000000" Clicked="BtnClickedAsync"
BackgroundColor="#50C6E0"
BorderWidth = "0"/>
```

And then Handle :

```
public async Task BtnSetLocationClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if(UsernameEntry.Text == "Your Default UserName" && PasswordEntry.Text=="Your Default PassWord")
    {
         //Navigate your page
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Invalid Credential", "Ok");
    }
}
```

In App.cs file :

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SettingClass.UserName))
                MainPage = new LoginPage();
else
      MainPage = new HomePage();
```

Add New class for Setting. Code is :

```
public static class SettingClass
{
    const string userNameKey = "UserName";
    const string userNameDefault = "";

    private static ISettings AppSettings
    {
        get { return CrossSettings.Current; }
    }

    public static string UserName
    {
        get => AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(userNameKey, userNameDefault);
        set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(userNameKey, value);
    }

}
```

Now you have to just add value in SettingClass.UserName and fetch in app initialize method.

Comment: i got error on PasswordEntry.Password = "admin"; red lines under the.Password

Comment: Sorry My mistake. Updated My code. Please check.

Comment: thanks. how do I add a username and password is correct should it go to new page and show it incorrect should it say that there is an incorrect username or password?

Comment: I have added code for checked credential.

Comment: i will test now

Comment: I think I have typed If instead of if. Please replace it.

Comment: Working fine now thanks

Comment: Okay. Great. You can Accept and upvote answer if you want. :)

Comment: has one last question. is it possible to add somehow a snap of button called remember me remembering username and password if you click remember me?

Comment: Means If user login once then don't ask for login again?

Comment: yes that i mean

Comment: Then you have to use Setting Plugins for Xamarin. You can store your credential and at initialized time you can check If user already logged in then navigate to another page. I am adding sample code for that.

Comment: thanks you Srusti. i will try to find out to put the code in right place

Comment: i only get error when i add the last code

Comment: Have you added Setting Plugin?

Comment: i have installed it

Comment: i installed the setting plugins before i tryd to add that code and just getting error

Comment: Have you followed step that mentioned in plugin document? Created one class?

Comment: looked a little but i can check some more

Comment: i'm have readed a little but not quaitly shore how it works

Comment: I have added code for setting class using that plugin. Please check that.

Comment: i allmost get it to work now i think but got error on: The type or namespace name 'DataService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry It was my mistake. It was not required. Just remove that line.

Comment: i removed it. and i got no errors but now i can't login after the edit

Comment: i used that login that you gave me but now it just stopped to work so i can't login to the app

Comment: This code is for just save your credential in device. It's not relate to any login code.

Comment: thanks. you have some idea to check whats happening?

Comment: if i remove the code in settingsclass.cs and .app back to MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Views.LoginPage()); the logging menu working very fine. but if i add the code in settingsclass.cs and add: if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SettingClass.UserName))
                MainPage = new Views.LoginPage();
            else
      MainPage = new MainPage(); then nothing happend when i try to login

Comment: some ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: No. Without whole code I can't give any Idea. What exactly you are doing I have to check that.

Comment: thanks. I have the code to but i just removed it in the project just for testing and see whats happed then. but i have the whole code in the project

Comment: So it's working or not?

Comment: not working at all

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: the issue is when i have the whole code nothing working in the app file, settingsclass and in the Loginpage nothing working. i juse the codes frome here. but if i not use the codes at all then it working but then the save settings not work becouse then its not there